# How to set a product to be in/out of stock programatically

Tags: inventory, ce-1.6.2.0

I tried a few snippets found online but with no success.

Just trying to set a product to be in stock / out of stock with code, this is as far as I've gotten:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( 'id' );

$stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty', 0);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 0);

$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```

It's making no changes to the product information when viewed through the admin panel, any ideas?

Comment: Your code is working for me, though, you have to have the setting to allow the stock to be managed via the backend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
```

and then set and save your changes as before.

Comment: Thanks for that, I solved the issue by manually switching to "manage stock" = yes in the admin panel. Once that's done, your code works perfectly.

Comment: this worked for magento 1.6

Comment: When i do this in an observer function, below error message is displaying The requested quantity for "Productname" is not available. is there any method $stockItem         = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($postProductId);$stockItem->setData('qty', $currentStock);                
                $stockItem->save();

Answer (score 8):

Try the following. you shouldn't have to load a new stock object

```
$product->setStockData(
   array( 
          'is_in_stock' => 0, 
          'qty' => 0,
          'manage_stock' => 1,
          'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1
   )
 );
```

And the just save the product as you did in your script

Comment: Does not work under 1.8 CE...

Comment: OP posted the question for ce1.6. But what exactly is not working. Does it throw an error?

Comment: Does work under 1.9 CE.

Answer (score 3):

As the addition to all answers it may be a good idea to use `addData` instead of `setData` in oder to be safe for updating the info and not only setting it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but with the difference that there wasn't any stock item object for a particular product. When this happens it's good to create the stock item object initially before setting the quantity (unless there is a way to them at the same time).

```
// Check if there is a stock item object
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();
if (empty($stockItemData)) {

    // Create the initial stock item object
    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock',1);
    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',$qty ? 1 : 0);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id',1);
    $stockItem->setData('product_id',$product->getId());
    $stockItem->setData('qty',0);
    $stockItem->save();

    // Init the object again after it has been saved so we get the full object
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
}

// Set the quantity
$stockItem->setData('qty',$qty);
$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```

Comment: `$product->save();` - is it required after saving `$stockItem`?

Comment: Probably not for stock item alone unless you're changing other product attributes.

Comment: Yes, because if you create it from scratch you need to add the stockItem to the product, an Observer will pick it up and save it later (so duplicate saving isn't recquired

Answer (score 3):

trying on magento 1.8.1.0 CE and couldn't save "qty" due to missing "type_id" value (for new item).
solved by

```
$stockItem->setTypeId( $product->getTypeId() );
```

Comment: Mate, took me a long time to find the right solution for my problem. You comment saved my life. Cheers!  ;-)

Comment: Saved my life too!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest a change to Raj's answer to support odd situations.  In order for the answer to work I had to comment out the if statement, because products created in a programmatic manner can have partial, yet incomplete, stock data. This was the only way that I was able to get it to work.

```
// Check if there is a stock item object
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItemData = $stockItem->getData();
//if (empty($stockItemData)) {
    // Create the initial stock item object
    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock',1);
    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',$qty ? 1 : 0);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id',1);
    $stockItem->setData('product_id',$product->getId());
    $stockItem->setData('qty',0);
    $stockItem->save();

    // Init the object again after it has been saved so we get the full object
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
//}

// Set the quantity
$stockItem->setData('qty',$qty);
$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible cause that cost me about 2 hours of work: I was trying this for ages wondering why it wouldn't save. I had an `exit;` php statement after the `->save()` and a bunch of echos so it wouldn't move onto the next screen automatically (to help debug).

However the commits to the database must occur late on in the page load it wouldn't save for me until I removed the `exit;`!

Answer (score 1):

As in other answers suggested one can use the class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` directly. But one has to reference the product correctly via a call to `setProduct` to have working code both for new and existing stock items.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItem->setProduct($product)
    ->setData('stock_id', Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID)
    ->setData('qty', 1)
    ->setData('is_in_stock', 1)
    ->setData('manage_stock', 1)
    ->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0)
    ->setData('use_config_backorders', 0)
    ->setData('backorders', 0)
    ->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0)
    ->setData('max_sale_qty', 1)                
    ->save();
```

### Alternative solution

However if you call `$product->save` anyway i would just set the stock data via `$product->setStockdata($array)` as follows. This way Magento creates a correct stock item from stock data. Big advantage is that the stock item update happens in the same transaction as `$product->save()`. This is important for data consistency.

```
$stockData = array();
$stockData['qty'] = 1;
$stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
$stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
$stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
$stockData['use_config_backorders'] = 0;
$stockData['backorders'] = 0;
$stockData['use_config_max_sale_qty'] = 0;
$stockData['max_sale_qty'] = 1;
$product->setStockData($stockData);
//...
$product->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my C# code

```
var inStock = qty > 0 ? 1 : 0;    
var stock_data = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity()
            {
                qty = qty,
                is_in_stock = inStock,
                manage_stock = 1,
                is_in_stockSpecified = true,
            };
```

`is_in_stockSpecified` is important

This is the output

[image]