# Bulk update configurable products

Tags: product

I recently migrated from Volusion to Magento using Cart2Cart.  Most of my products are configurable and are showing "Out of Stock" and quantities set to zero.  I have 5,000 products (including variations).  My question is, is there a way to do a either do a bulk update, or at least have access to a page where I can see all products at once with the option of setting stock values from that page?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programatically via a script or an extension. What you need is to load magento object, load product collection

```
    //load Magento
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('admin');

    //load products collection        
    $productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach($productsCollection as $item) {

    //load product object
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
    //set Is in stock to Yes 
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->save();
    $product->save();
}
```

[For more information check this thread (perhaps you need to set Manage Stock=Yes, Qty etc.)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/how-to-set-a-product-to-be-in-out-of-stock-programatically)

After @Marius brilliant answer I decided to update my answer by providing few alternatives in case you don't need the same QTY for ALL products.

1) What you can do is to use [Magento Dataflow - Import/Export Profile](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles). You need to export your products, change Qty field and if you enabled the stock control in the administration area I believe this would solve the problem.
2) Also you could check [Magmi Mass Importer as it allows to update products](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page)
3) And here you can check [MASS UPDATE STOCK LEVELS IN MAGENTO – FAST](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mass-update-stock-levels-in-magento-fast/) by @Sonassi

Comment: This may work for a few products, but for 5k products...your grandchildren will graduate from college before the script ends.

Comment: agreed for 50k or 500k but 5k not that bad. Would be curious to read the better solution (I know that $product->save() is very very slow, but not that slow as I'm planning to attend my grandchildren graduation in 50 years as earliest :) )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the same qty for all the products you can run this query on your db.

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` 
SET 
    `qty` = 5000,
    `is_in_stock` = 1
```

Then rebuild your indexes.

Comment: Brilliant answer if @Brent needs the same qty to all products. Upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate it.  Running that query Marius provided did what I needed.  Thanks again!