# Out of stock item not changing even the quantity is greater the 0

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, stock, status

I have version 1.9 loaded the problem is, I update the stock via csv file. When the item goes 0 it change to "out of stock" but when the quantity increase greater then 0 it doesn't change back to "in stock". It still says quantity 29 "out of stock" and all out of stock items do not show on our front end. so I am losing customers on item which I actually have in stock. 
I have over 50000 items so can not change everything manually.

Any idea how can I resolve this issue please? Magento should change the status automatically when quantity become greater than 0.

Comment: Have you done reindex? and are these products are enabled and set to visible on frontend?

Comment: **is_in_stock** is also required, plus a stock status index run

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the status for each product.

The good thing is that it has been done before:

[How to set a product to be in/out of stock programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/how-to-set-a-product-to-be-in-out-of-stock-programatically)

You have to loop through your products and apply the snippet in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but someone may have similar issue.  If you are updating via csv as you say you are, couldn't you just include the column "is_in_stock" with the value "1" (as well as your "qty" of 29).  That way, when the stock level is updated the availability will be updated too.

That's how I do it.  I do use an extension ('Custom Bulk Product Import..." by Commerce Extensions via Magento Connect) which is pretty solid, but I expect other methods allow you to import this field too possibly even magento's standard methods, and I'm sure the popular Magmi would.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSV file create an additional column `Stock STATUS` which u`pdates the status to 1 (when in stock) and 0 (out of stock)`. Until `2013 I used to update stock with following column headers in my CSV file`: Product id, Sku Stock, QTY, Stock STATUS

```
Stock STATUS column had formula =IF(C2=0,0,1) Column C = Sku Stock
```